# How do non-trinitarians reconcile Jesus' claims to be God, and the Father to be God, with the requirement for monotheism?

Tags: trinity, non-trinitarian, monotheism

John said the Word was with God and was God (John 1:1), and the Word became flesh (John 1:14)—Jesus.

Jesus said "Before Abraham was I AM" (John 8:58)—Jesus' claim to be YHVH.

Jesus acknowledged the Father to be God.

However YHVH says there are no other gods beside Him (Exodus 20:3; Deuteronomy 5:7; Deuteronomy 4:35; Deuteronomy 4:39).

Trinitarianism is a solution to this.  How do non-trinitarians resolve the clear indications that both the Father and Jesus are God?

Comment: John didn't speak English. :) "The logos *became-was-came in* the flesh." What does it mean? The verb 'egeneto' is a vague verb. "Before Abraham *was-was born-came to be-comes to be(!)*, *I am-I am he-I am the one*." Again, what does it mean? So your argument depends on certain interpretations of what, especially with John 8:58, are debatable verses.

Comment: But in a nut-shell, Jesus is God in the sense of agency, not ontology. The Christ is the Father's authorized agent or deputized representative.

Comment: But your 3rd sentence is right - Jesus didn't only acknowledge the Father to be God, but to be the *only* true God! (John 17:3) Do you have a Biblical reference for "YHVH says there are no other gods beside Him"?

Comment: The question re John 1:1 is already asked here for Unitarians. https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/54906/how-do-unitarians-interpret-john-11 A question re John 8:58 that impinges on this question is here https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91430/what-are-our-options-for-how-jesus-pre-existed-at-john-858

Comment: If you're not looking for binitarian answers, might want to tighten up the scope on the question.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather i actually like the binitarian answer

Comment: OK, but it's not clear how it engages with the question, as the question is about claims that Jesus is God and monotheism, not the HS. *Shrug*.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather I like answers that expand me.   Others can down vote answers they feel don't address the question.

Comment: You selected it as the answer. The question posed is basically a non-problem for binitarians. *Double-shrug*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until the incarnation, YHWH alone dealt with humanity.
Until Jesus revealed him, the world had no knowledge of the Father.
It wasn't until less than 2000 years ago that humanity learned of the existence of the Father.

The writers of the Hebrew scriptures knew only of YHWH, their only God.
And YHWH spoke to the prophets as their only God.

So is there really a "requirement for monotheism", or do the Hebrew scriptures simply record that in practice Israel was monotheistic?

---

Consider the relationship between God the Father and God the Son, and their desire for more children.
This relationship is symbolized in the physical world by family, hence the terms "father" and "son".

If one considers "God" to be a family (currently with only 2 members), then there *is* only one "God" or godhead.

In John 10:30, Jesus said "*I and the Father are one.*".
He didn't mean this as a doctrine that the Catholic Church calls a "mystery" that no human can comprehend, he simply meant that they are united in purpose, acting in harmony and perfect agreement.

If one sees "God" as a family, there is, and always will be, only one "God".

See also:

- [The God Family | United Church of God](https://www.ucg.org/bible-study-tools/booklets/why-were-you-born/the-god-family).
- [What Is God Really Like? | Living Church of God](https://www.tomorrowsworld.org/magazines/2004/january-february/what-is-god-really-like#:%7E:text=god%20is%20a%20family)

Comment: Exodus 4:22-23, Isaiah 1:2, Isaiah 63:16, Malachi 1:6, 1 Chronicles 29:10All testify God was known as Father by His people in OT.

Comment: @steveowen. Yes, the writers did compare YHWH's relationship with Israel as a father, but they also compare it as a spouse, with references to adultery and divorce. They are metaphors, not contradictions.

Comment: *God the Son* - this is an imaginary construct not found in all the pages of scripture. If as you righty say, *they are united in purpose*, then they are two not one at all. How can ONE be united? This bizarre construct is trinitarianism with a leg missing. Jesus came to do the *Father's will* - not his own - two wills in this strange arrangement of a duality of God.

Comment: This is clearly not a non-trinitarian response, and therefore cannot address what the questioner was asking (i.e. it doesn't answer the question).  The use of the eisegetical (unbiblical) term "God the Son" is a huge giveaway, as no non-trinitarian would ever accept the use of this term.

Comment: @Biblasia, it definitely *is* non-trinitarian. There is no suggestion that God's holy spirit is a person, and if you look at the references they quite explicitly reject the Trinity Doctrine. There are more than two views of what God is: atheist, unitarian, binitarian, trinitarian, Trinitarian, polytheistic, etc. What I presented is a *binitarian* view.

Comment: @RayButterworth  Atheism seems rather out of scope for this question, and if there is a distinction in belief systems between "trinitarian" and "Trinitarian", I am ignorant of it. You have been heretofore posting as a trinitarian.  Are you shifting, now, toward binitarianism?

Comment: @Biblasia "*You have been heretofore posting as a trinitarian*". I might have posted explanations from that point of view, but I personally believe that there is no biblical basis for the concept. But on this site, one's personal beliefs shouldn't affect one's answers. ¶ I use "trinitarian" to mean the belief that the godhead is composed of three persons, and "Trinitarian" to apply the Catholic "Trinitarian Doctrine" to it. A small-t trinitarian believes in the Holy Ghost, but doesn't think there is a "mystery" relationship that somehow magically turns the three persons into a single person.

Comment: @RayButterworth  I personally believe that it would be wrong for me to promote something that I know is untrue.  In the spirit of 1 Peter 3:15, my answers are all influenced by my beliefs--though I seek to ground my beliefs always in a solid "thus saith the Lord."  Your distinction between "trinitarian" and "Trinitarian" is interesting, but I have never seen anyone else use it in this way.  Neither the Catholic trinity nor the trinity of anyone else is biblical, howevermuch people might desire to think otherwise.  The Catholics do, at least, believe the Trinity to be a single Being.

Comment: @Biblasia, understanding and explaining a different belief isn't the same as *promoting* it. Any questions like that would have asked for answers from a specific position. ¶ "*Neither the Catholic trinity nor the trinity of anyone else is biblical,*" — we agree on that (and steveowen too I assume). ¶ "*The Catholics do, at least, believe the Trinity to be a single Being.*" but only by allowing that the the concept itself can never truly be understood.

Comment: @Biblasia Not to really jump into a disagreement between two persons, but it's perfectly normal to teach concepts you don't believe in. Especially when it comes to faith. I accepted this answer since it helped me the most

Comment: God is a family? Huh....what?  The Godhood is a family.  You can be a child of God too.

Answer (score 4):

### God was in Christ

When Jesus spoke as God, it was because God was in him, and the words were not his but God's.  He tells us this himself.  This is the point upon which multitudes stumble, because Jesus does sound like God speaking--but he told us plainly that the Father was the only true God, and that the words he spoke were not his words but those of the Father.

As Jesus said to Philip:

> Believest thou not that I am in the Father, and the Father in me? the
> words that I speak unto you I speak not of myself: but the Father that
> dwelleth in me, he doeth the works. (John 14:10, KJV)

And he gave this same consistent message elsewhere as well.

> Then said Jesus unto them, When ye have lifted up the Son of man, then
> shall ye know that I am he, and that I do nothing of myself; but as my
> Father hath taught me, I speak these things. (John 8:28, KJV)
>
> But if I do, though ye believe not me, believe the works: that ye may
> know, and believe, that the Father is in me, and I in him. (John
> 10:38, KJV)
>
> For I have not spoken of myself; but the Father which sent me, he gave
> me a commandment, what I should say, and what I should speak. (John
> 12:49, KJV)

Many today are as unbelieving as was Philip.  They don't believe that the Father was in Christ.  They think Christ spoke only his own words, on his own volition, rather than the words of the Father.  This is also what the Pharisees thought--and what caused them to accuse Jesus of blasphemy when he offered words of forgiveness to sinners.

Yet the Bible plainly tells us that God was in Christ.

> To wit, that **God was in Christ, reconciling the world unto himself,**
> not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed unto us
> the word of reconciliation. (2 Corinthians 5:19, KJV)

So, ironically, it is the Trinitarians who fail to recognize the presence of two beings within the person of Christ.  They instead elevate Christ to Godhead, believing the Man to be God, even against plain Bible statements to the contrary.

### God is not human.

> **God is not a man**, that he should lie; **neither the son of man,** that he
> should repent: hath he said, and shall he not do it? or hath he
> spoken, and shall he not make it good? (Numbers 23:19, KJV)
>
> And also the Strength of Israel will not lie nor repent: for **he is not
> a man,** that he should repent. (1 Samuel 15:29, KJV)

God is not a man, and there is not one text of scripture that contradicts this.  Not one text says Jesus was God.

### The Spirit of Antichrist

Jesus' own teachings help us to see that Trinitarians not only have the wrong belief about who he was, but also have the spirit of antichrist, as I will next explain.

Consider these texts:

**Jesus is not a spirit: he has flesh and bones, spirits do not.**

> Behold my hands and my feet, that it is I myself: handle me, and see;
> for a spirit hath not flesh and bones, as ye see me have. (Luke 24:39,
> KJV)

**But God is a spirit.**

> God is a Spirit: and they that worship him must worship him in spirit
> and in truth. (John 4:24, KJV)

**Those who do not confess Jesus came in the flesh have the spirit of antichrist.**

> <sup>2</sup> Hereby know ye the Spirit of God: Every spirit that
> confesseth that Jesus Christ is come in the flesh is of God:
> <sup>3</sup> And every spirit that confesseth not that Jesus Christ is
> come in the flesh is not of God: and this is that spirit of
> antichrist, whereof ye have heard that it should come; and even now
> already is it in the world. (1 John 4:2-3, KJV)

Trinitarians claim that Jesus is God.  Jesus taught that God is a spirit, and said spirits do not have flesh and bones as he had.  Therefore, to say Jesus is God is to say he could not have come in the flesh.  That is the Biblical definition of having the spirit of antichrist.

### Conclusion

Jesus never claimed to be God.  His claim was that of being **the Son of God.**  But that Jesus spoke as God is clear, for he tells us that his words were those of the Father.  And Jesus taught that the Father was the only true God (John 17:1-3), and that the Father was both *his* God and *our* God (John 20:17).

Comment: Jesus had the spirit of God without measure (John 3:34).  All of God (who is spirit) dwelt in Jesus (who is flesh).  The dichotomy you try to draw in your "spirit of antichrist" proof does not exist...God is spirit and Jesus is both.

Comment: @MikeBorden Can God divide His spirit and have only part of it inhabit Christ? Nothing that I said above would even hint at such a thing. In fact, you have not gone quite far enough even in your statement here, because the Bible says: "For in him dwelleth **all the fulness of the Godhead** bodily." (Col. 2:9). What you might, however, be mindful of is that God is spirit, and can be everywhere present.  God is not limited to a specific location. Jesus is a man in whom God dwelt. Jesus died, but God cannot, and did not die. Had Jesus been God, he could also never have been tempted (James 1:13).

Comment: What would be the purpose of saying "without measure" and "all the fullness" if not to set Christ apart from all others.  God "dwelled" in a special way in the temple, even though the spirit is everywhere present, and Jews went there to approach God.  Now God dwells in a temple of flesh, made without hands, and when one "goes to" Jesus one "goes to" God.  This union of God (spirit) and temple (flesh) is complete and permanent.

Comment: *Jesus Christ in/to to flesh having come* is what 1 John 4 says.  It does not say that he suddenly began to exist but that he came in flesh.  This is what the spirit of antichrist will not confess.

Comment: @MikeBorden  When you say Jesus is God, you deny that he could possibly have been flesh, because Jesus taught plainly that God is (a) spirit, and that he himself was not (a) spirit.  Either you believe Jesus when he says he has flesh and bones, or you do not.  Either you believe Jesus when he says he is not a spirit, or you do not.  It is not possible to have it both ways because Jesus himself was too clear on it.  He said he was not a spirit, but that God is a spirit.  If you believe the Man himself, you accept that he was come in the flesh, and was not God.

Comment: @MikeBorden  Jesus came as our Example.  When God inhabited his "temple," it was an example of how God will dwell in our body temples, too.  It is when God's spirit dwells in us that we are enabled to be overcomers and obedient to God's will.  If, however, we believe that Jesus was God, then we presume that he had some unfair advantage over us that we cannot have, and this is one of Satan's best tools to keep us from persevering--from enduring to the end.  We give up too quickly, thinking that "to err is human."  Thus this theological error is verily tragic and dangerous.  The Man--1 Tim. 2:5.

Comment: Appearing in the upper room, Jesus needed to comfort the disciples that he was not a ghost.  He is not speaking regarding deity here but merely the fact that he appeared in a locked room.  He was born without sin and had the fullness of deity in him...  that is an advantage and thankfully we can partake of it.  We are born again and then we can persevere to the end because the spirit of Christ is in us.  That is the hope of glory...Christ in us.   To follow some merely human example is folly and vanity, for the flesh is too weak.

Comment: @MikeBorden The word Jesus used in all these passages is "pneuma" in Greek.  Jesus said he was _not_ "pneuma" and that God _was_ "pneuma."  Some translations obscure this by translating as "ghost" in place of "spirit."

Comment: @stkuser *Jesus was a spirit person before being a human on the earth*. This is opinion and not a scriptural idea.

Comment: Luke 24:37  Did the disciples think they had seen God?  You would have to demonstrate that each use of *pneuma* refers to God for your point to carry weight (Hebrews 1:14).  Context is extremely important for proper exegesis.

Comment: @MikeBorden  A Bible scholar should know that "pneuma" has different senses of meaning, depending on context.  So does "soul" in English, which in many contexts applies only to humans, in some contexts to the human passions or thoughts, and in some contexts it applies even to animals.  But these statements of Jesus directly address the _substance_ of the one to whom Jesus refers, i.e. the actually _being,_ and it is with direct, definition-type, statements as in "God is spirit" and "a spirit does not have flesh...as ye see me have", i.e. "I am not (a) spirit."  These usages are fully parallel.

Comment: @MikeBorden _"Did the disciples think they had seen God?"_ John 1:18 is pretty clear on this point:  "No man hath seen God **at any time,** the only begotten Son, which is in the bosom of the Father, he hath declared him." (John 1:18, KJV).  That's quite definitive, written by John, ostensibly the disciple closest to Jesus.

Comment: Its really great to see the true Monotheist coming out in strength and unity to explain very simply who is our God and Father.  We have nothing to hide...We welcome the tough questions because we walk in the light.  Ask away.....  challenge us because iron sharpens iron.

Comment: @stkuser Unfortunately you have a traditional premise through which the scriptures are read. The Gospels state how and when Jesus originated - nothing about him being before that. Persisting with his pre-existence creates many contradictions. Allowing scripture to interpret scripture solves all such issues. Please see https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/69276/what-does-jesus-mean-ascending-to-where-he-was-before/70870?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C56.3759#70870

Comment: Perhaps https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/59811/in-what-sense-did-jesus-descend-come-from-heaven-john-313-331/59846?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C42.1322#59846

Comment: @stkuser If Satan is the 'god' of this world, we can say Jesus is also a god - but he cannot be THE God because THE God is Jesus' God. John 20:17 I am ascending to my Father and your Father, to my God and your God.’ Jesus the firstborn of all creation Col 1:15, Ram 8:29 means he is the first human to go from mortality to immortality. These things are 'not what I believe', but what the Bible explicitly teaches.

Comment: @stkuser I believe that Jesus' divinity and Michael are one and the same, and that Michael is God's manifestation to His creatures, God Himself being invisible even to angels. It is through Michael/Jesus that God has chosen to reveal himself throughout eternity. No one has seen God, for He is invisible (see 1 Tim. 1:17; 6:16; John 1:18). As "Michael", Jesus has always been God's "Son"--but Michael is not a created being, he has always existed. Only Jesus' humanity could be tempted and subject to death--God cannot be tempted. The exact nature of God is a mystery we should not seek to penetrate.

Comment: @Biblasia most of your last comment is opinion not supported by scripture. *Michael is not a created being*? *Jesus has always been God's "Son"?

Comment: @steveowen  John 3:16 tells us that God so loved the world that He gave his only begotten son.  He could not have given us a son He did not have.  Revelation 13:8 tells us that the Lamb was slain from the foundation of the world--indicating there was a Lamb to be slain at the time of Creation.

Comment: @Biblasia I'm afraid you have to grasp the difference between figurative and literal. The Gospels explain how and when Jesus began - do you disregard their simple revelation? Jesus was *figuratively* slain because he was always the core of God's plan of salvation before sin even happened. We know when Jesus was slain - ~2000 years ago!

Comment: The point is that (v. 37) they thought they had seen a "pneuma" and Jesus comforted them (v. 39) that he was not a "pneuma".  Contextually, this has nothing to do with the nature of deity.  God is "pneuma", that is true, but so are angels and there were also some in prison (1 Peter 3:19).  Not every "pneuma" is God.

Comment: @MikeBorden The word "pneuma" is contrasted with flesh in the context of beings.  Either one is flesh or one is spirit. This is a different context/usage than when speaking of one's own "spirit" in the context of body+spirit = soul / person.  In that context, spirit might refer to merely the breath, though there is another Greek word that is very closely related as well.  Spirits of humans are not separate, "out of body" beings--the human context differs from that of the "elohim" (to use a Hebraism).  Yes, angels are spirits--but they are not merely breath.  As always, context is meaningful.

Comment: You cannot make the disciples think they had seen a spirit and Jesus respond to that thought by denying that he is God unless you completely disregard the context of the passage.  In Christ one is both flesh and spirit, having been born and then born again.  The hard distinction you make evaporates in Christ.

Comment: @MikeBorden. Be careful.  Jesus regularly answers questions that were not asked.  He goes straight to the real point of something, and would sometimes confuse the disciples as to why he had said something.  Nicodemus asked Jesus a question that got one of those off-the-wall responses as well--but Jesus was going straight to the real heart of the issue, cutting away the preliminaries.  Such was his habit.  While context _is_ important, it is no replacement for common sense nor spiritual discernment.  Jesus may very well have used the opportunity to express an important spiritual truth.

Comment: Just as you say; Jesus often responds to the deeper, unasked question.  The thing is, when Jesus answers that way, it is evident from the context not despite the context.

Comment: @MikeBorden And that is just as I read this passage.  It is evident from the context that Jesus is trying to correct the disciples' misconceptions about spirits, in addition to setting them straight as to his own identity.

Comment: I believe that is, indeed, an addition:)

Answer (score 2):

*Before Abraham was I AM*, This doesn't say anything about Jesus being God. This must be read in.

What does 'before Abraham' mean?

Paul gives a clue in Gal 3:16

> The promises were spoken to Abraham and to his seed. Scripture does not say "and to seeds," meaning many people, but "and to your seed," meaning one person, who is Christ.

So, quite unequivocally, Paul tells us what the ‘before’ means. Jesus was the one to come, yet he was *planned* well before Abraham existed. He would be the *descendant* of Abraham!

Our texts do not say, ‘before Abraham, I existed’.

The phrase egō eimi or ‘I am’ is used in the NT by other people who certainly are not God or claiming to be God. To hang desperately to this “I am” from Jesus is to ignore other texts that are exactly the same and simply refer to the person in context. Jesus is saying nothing more than “I am the one”, “It is I”. Before Abraham, ‘I am the one’ that he looked forward to. ‘My day’, has just begun!

The man born blind John 9:9, ‘I am (he)’ egō eimi Matt 14:27 Take courage, it is I. Don’t be afraid. Mk 6:50 John 6:20 egō eimi The disciples said, ‘Surely you don't mean me, Lord?" egō eimi Matt 26:22, John 8:28 ‘you will know that I am he…’ egō eimi

While some gravitate to this ‘I am’ construct, it must align with the rest of the NT. Which is silent on Jesus being God from Matt to Rev.

Jesus said he had the same God all men do which makes him not God.

> But go find my brothers and tell them, ‘I am ascending to my Father and your Father, to my God and your God.’ John 20:17

Jesus makes no claim to be God. All the Bible provides is some ambiguous passages which can be understood in a manner^ which creates contradictions with the rest of the NT. Every NT writer teaches that Jesus is a man only, yet without sin.

The 'word' you refer to in John 1:1-3 is *not yet* Jesus. He is the *result* of the logos becoming flesh ~2000 years ago. The logos was *with* God, Jesus was not. Jesus was born of Mary (Gal 4:4) as the Gospels clearly express. Jesus is *now* with God - at His right hand.

^ by reading out of context, by partially quoting verses or by using very poor or biased 'translations'.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140160/discussion-on-answer-by-steveowen-how-do-non-trinitarians-reconcile-jesus-claim).

Answer (score 0):

**The theological basis for this response**

This answer is based on the Bible interpretations and Christian theology put forth by [Emanuel Swedenborg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanuel_Swedenborg) (1688-1772), which is the basis for the Bible interpretations and theology of the various New Church, or Swedenborgian, denominations that were founded after his death.

- This theology is not *[unitarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarianism)* as that is usually defined, because Swedenborg stated that the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit are all fully divine, and are God.
- This theology is not *[trinitarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity)* as that is usually defined, because although Swedenborg stated that there is a Trinity in God, he denied that the Trinity consists of three persons, but stated that Father, Son, and Holy Spirit exist in a single person of God.
- It is also not *[modalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabellianism),* as explained in [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/40799/whats-the-difference-if-any-between-the-swedenborgian-and-oneness-pentecostal/40912#40912).

From a Swedenborgian Christian perspective, it is trinitarians themselves who have not met the requirements for monotheism, as covered in [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/42211/what-is-the-basis-for-the-swedenborgian-view-that-the-most-common-concept-of-god/42212#42212).

***Note**:* This answer will not attempt to provide a full biblical basis for its statements, as that basis is so extensive that doing so would swell this answer far beyond the character limits imposed by this website. For those who want the full biblical basis behind this answer, I refer you to *[True Christianity](https://leewoof.org/2014/06/22/true-christianity-by-emanuel-swedenborg/),* volume 1, by Emanuel Swedenborg. (The link is to my own book notice for this book.)

To properly answer this question, I must divide it into several points, the first being:

**1. Jesus was not fully divine at birth**

According to the Gospels, Mary, an ordinary human being, was Jesus' mother, whereas God was his Father. This means that at the time of his birth, Jesus had both a finite, limited, sin-prone human nature from his human mother Mary and an infinite, unlimited, eternal divine nature from his divine Father.

This dual nature, finite human and infinite divine, persisted throughout Jesus' lifetime on earth. It was not until after the Resurrection that he was fully divine, having by that time replaced all the finite humanity that came from his human mother with an infinite divine humanity that was the expression of his inner divine nature, which was God, also known as the Father.

During his lifetime on earth, Jesus' conscious awareness alternated between his finite human side and his infinite divine side. This is why he sometimes speaks to, and of, the Father as if to, or of, a separate being, and other times says that he is one with the Father, and that everything he says and does is from the Father within.

Without an understanding of Jesus' process of "glorification," or becoming fully divine, during his lifetime on earth, it is impossible to understand and reconcile the various statements by and about him in the Gospels and in the rest of the New Testament.

For a fuller explanation of these points, please see [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/42570/how-does-the-swedenborgian-church-explain-passages-where-jesus-talks-prays-to-th/42609#42609).

**2. During Jesus' lifetime on earth, he was literally the Son of God**

Because Jesus had a human mother and a divine Father, during his lifetime on earth he was quite literally the Son of God.

Every human being is the son or daughter of his or her human father through that person's father having impregnated that person's mother, resulting in his or her conception and birth.

Similarly, Mary was impregnated by a father, but in this case it was the divine Father, resulting in Jesus' conception and birth. Therefore Jesus was the Son of God via Mary.

**3. After the Resurrection and Ascension, Jesus was no longer literally, but figuratively the Son of God**

As stated above, during his lifetime on earth, Jesus gradually replaced everything that came from his human mother with a divine humanity that was the expression of the divine Father. At the time of his Resurrection, he was therefore no longer the son of Mary, since there was nothing left of Mary in him.

This means that at the time of the Resurrection, he was no longer *literally* the Son of God. Rather, he was simply *God,* because:

**4. God is indivisible; therefore Jesus never separated from the Father**

Every human being born on this earth separates from both father and mother, and becomes a distinct person of his or her own.

With God's divine self, this is not possible. God is fully and utterly *One,* and cannot be divided into more than one. Therefore, since God, known as the Father, was Jesus' own inner being, Jesus never separated from his Father, but instead became more and more one with his Father.

This is the same as saying that Jesus, as he replaced everything from his human mother with the divinity of his Father, became fully one with God, and became, quite simply, God.

**5. Father, Son, and Holy Spirit are not three Persons of God, but three "essential components," or in more ordinary language, "parts" of God.**

Although, as stated above, during his lifetime on earth Jesus was literally the Son of God, this literal sonship lasted only during his lifetime on earth.

Once Jesus' lifetime on earth was complete, and he ascended to the Father, this literal sonship no longer existed. Rather, Father, Son, and Holy Spirit are *metaphors* for three essential components (Latin: *essentialia*) of God.

Unlike the Nicene Trinity of Persons, which no one can really understand, this Trinity in one Person of God is very easy to understand. Genesis 1:26–27 says that we humans, both male and female, are created in the image and likeness of God. Therefore if there is a Trinity in God, there must also be a trinity in human beings. Using us humans as an example, here is how we can understand the Trinity in one Person of God:

- "The Father" mentioned in the Bible is like our soul.
- "The Son" is like our body.
- "The Holy Spirit" is like everything we say and do.

Even a five-year-old can easily understand this.

More abstractly:

- The Father is the *Divine Love*
- The Son is *Divine Truth*
- The Holy Spirit is *Divine Power*

These are not three Persons—which is polytheism—but three "essential components" of God, who is fully and completely One, both in essence and in person.

For a fuller explanation of the true biblical Trinity in the One Person of God, please see this article on my website:

[Who is God? Who is Jesus Christ? What about that Holy Spirit?](https://leewoof.org/2012/09/17/who-is-god-who-is-jesus-christ-what-about-that-holy-spirit/)

**6. Swedenborg's Trinity in one Person resolves all the thorny biblical issues about the nature of God**

If we understand all of these points, and several more that there is not time to delve into here, all of the statements about Jesus in the Gospels, the Acts, and the Epistles, and all of the prophecies of Jesus in the Law, the Prophets, and the Psalms, make complete and beautiful sense, with no difficulties and no contradictions.

**7. Scripture quotations from the question**

To take up just the few passages mentioned in the question itself:

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. He was in the beginning with God. All things came into being through him, and without him not one thing came into being. What has come into being in him was life, and the life was the light of all people. The light shines in the darkness, and the darkness did not overtake it. . . . And the Word became flesh and lived among us, and we have seen his glory, the glory as of a father’s only son, full of grace and truth. (John 1:1–5, 14)

Here "God" is the same as "the Father." It represents the divine Soul, which is love ([1 John 4:8, 16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20John%204%3A8%2C%2016&version=NRSVUE)). "The Word" represents the divine Wisdom, which is the light mentioned in the rest of the passage. It was through Divine Wisdom that Divine Love created all things.

And it was as divine wisdom, or divine truth, that Jesus, who is the light of the world (John 8:12, 9:5), came to earth. This is why it says that "the Word became flesh and lived among us."

Divine Love and Divine Wisdom are not the same as one another, hence they are "with" one another. But they are also both fully and inseparably God, so that the Word also *was* God.

It is in this same sense that the Father and the Son are not the same, hence they are "with" one another. But they are also both fully and inseparably One God, so the Son *is* God, just as the Father *is* God. The Father is the Divine Love, and the Son is the Divine Wisdom manifesting the Divine Love to humans both on earth and in heaven.

> Jesus said to them, "Very truly, I tell you, before Abraham was, I am." (John 8:58)

Here Jesus is speaking from his inner divine being, or divine soul. During his lifetime, when Jesus' conscious awareness was in his inner divine being, he spoke of himself as the same being as God, the Father. This is why here, contrary to what some claim, Jesus *did* say that he was God.

Though many people today don't understand this, his listeners understood his meaning very clearly. That is why, in the very next verse, it says that they picked up stones to stone him. Two chapters later they explain *why* they picked up stones to stone him: "The Jews answered, 'It is not for a good work that we are going to stone you but for blasphemy, because you, though only a human, are making yourself God'" (John 10:33).

Unfortunately, through the centuries of increasingly false "Christianity," the clear meaning of Jesus' words has been lost, such that some people can claim that nowhere does Jesus say he is God. Further, after his Resurrection, when he *was* fully God, Thomas, one of his disciples, addressed him as "My Lord and my God" (John 20:28), and Jesus did not correct him.

Jesus knew that he was God. However, during his lifetime he also had a human side that was not God. This is why the Gospels don't *explicitly* call him God until after the Resurrection.

About this statement in the question:

> Jesus acknowledged the Father to be God.

Yes. Because his Father *was* God. And Jesus himself said that he and the Father are one ([John 10:30](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2010%3A30&version=NRSVUE)), and that those who have seen him have seen the Father ([John 14:9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2014%3A9&version=NRSVUE)). In other words, Jesus was, as the Gospel of Matthew tells us, "God with us" (Matthew 1:23).

> You shall have no other gods before me. (Exodus 20:3; Deuteronomy 5:7)

This, also, is why Jesus, after his process of glorification, could be no other than *God.* Not some supposed unbiblical "Second Person" of God, but *God.* And this is why Jesus himself, in prophecy and in the New Testament, is also called "Father." For more on this, please see this article on my website:

[Is it Right to Call Jesus "Father"?](https://leewoof.org/2019/04/04/is-it-right-to-call-jesus-father/)

**Conclusion**

Once we recognize that the Son of God is not some unbiblical "eternally begotten Second Person of the Trinity," but rather is God himself come to be with us, to teach us, and to save us, just as the Bible says, all the problems about God being fully and completely *One* disappear.

There are not three Persons of God. Conceptually and in reality, [that is simply three gods](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/42211/what-is-the-basis-for-the-swedenborgian-view-that-the-most-common-concept-of-god/42212#42212), which is polytheism.

No, there is one God and that God is the Lord God Jesus Christ.

I realize that I have hardly done justice to these points here. If you want to know the biblical truth that will set you free from all these biblical "contradictions," please do yourself a favor: read Swedenborg's book *[True Christianity](https://leewoof.org/2014/06/22/true-christianity-by-emanuel-swedenborg/).* Then all the mystery and confusion of Nicene Christianity will be cleared from your mind. Then you will have a clear path to seek and know the true God, who is One both in essence and in person, and who is with us personally as our Lord, God, and Savior, Jesus Christ.

Answer (score 0):

It actually seems most certain that God the Father and Jesus Christ the Son are separate beings; Jesus was not praying to himself or throwing his voice in Gethsemane. How about when he said on the cross, "Father, why hast thou forsaken me?" (Matthew 27:46) Forsaken means to leave entirely. Was he asking, "Why have I left myself?" because that doesn't make sense in two ways. He *left himself*? And he *didn't know why* he left *himself*?  We really need to realize that the idea of them being one being was just a thought by imperfect, limited human beings and move on to reason and sense.

But I guess I could also mention these scriptures that clearly describe them as separate beings: John 1:18, Acts 7:55, 56, and Colossians 3:1, how about John 8: 7-18, where Jesus wants to make it very clear that Jesus and God are two separate beings. It reads, "It is written in your law, that the testimony of TWO men is true. I am one that bears witness of myself, and the father that sent me beareth of me." If Jesus and God are one and the same, Jesus wouldn't have been able to make that statement. I can only imagine how they feel, seeing that we still think they are one.

And [this page](https://www.tedmontgomery.com/bblovrvw/emails/JesusGodandman.html) may help you if it is possible that you still don't think so.

#### So why a dispute?

They are both parts of the same *Godhead*, they are all part of managing the Father's plan. They are all *one God* (John 10:30), just like a married man and woman are "*one flesh*" (Matthew 19:5), or do you suppose that he meant for married couples to become like conjoined twins?  Does that make sense?
***Edit:*** The point is that a husband and wife are not literally one person, but are considered "one" because when they get married, her goals and concerns become his goals and concerns, and vice versa. And this is what Non-Trinitarians believe Jesus means when he says "I and the Father are one" (John 10:30).

#### Edit for disclaimers:

1. I cannot specify what type of Non-Trinitarian subset of beliefs these are, but they are scripture, and so it seems to me that, if you believe the Bible, and do not see any loopholes to how this doesn't clarify them as separate beings, that this is the belief of your religion.
2. I gave my sources, please do not say that ***I*** am saying something, when it is what *the **scriptures** that I site* are saying, that seems to be a common thing on this site.
3. I put a lot of attention and care into my posts, please actually read it over *carefully* before ***thinking*** that you know what I'm saying, and arguing against *what I'm **not** saying*.

Comment: No, it still doesn't make sense. You say Jesus and Father are separate, yet you say they are 'one God'. This is not scriptural as you suggest. Jesus has a God and still does - therefore he cannot be that God.

Comment: @steveowen, You are truly not understanding what I'm saying, and I cannot understand how you're not. The point is, you could also say that a husband and wife are not *literally* one flesh, but they are *one* in the sense that they now share the same goals and interests; her goals become his goals and vice versa. When the scriptures (*not **me***) say, "I and the father are one,"(John 10:30) notice **the scriptures say** that, **not me**, they are not saying they are literally the same person, but speaking like I said above.

Comment: Considering the question I am answering, you really should've known that I was not saying they are one being, I wish you had just read my entire post before commenting. You clearly did not.

Comment: No, I read it many times and agree on most everything. I just don’t understand your inclusion of Godhead.

Comment: @steveowen, Stated clearly, God, his Son, and the Holy Spirit are three, separate, individual beings, but the Son, Jesus Christ, once called Jehovah (if you don't know this I could talk in chat), and the Holy Spirit are so central to carrying out God's plans, and entrusted with so much of God the Father's power and authority, and they are so united to each other, that they are all "one". Basically, it just means they do not each have different causes and goals, one does not feel differently about what is sad or what is good than how the other two feel. In this sense, they are "one".

Comment: The Son and the Holy Spirit have been put, to a small degree, into God's position (By the Father).

Comment: Ok there’s the core issue that is now revealed.  The holy spirit is not an entity according to scripture. Happy to leave it there, I have a few posts about why the holy spirit is not a person in a godhead.

Comment: @steveowen, Could you give me the names or links of those posts? Also, I do not see that as a core issue, because even that set aside, as I may be incorrect on that, the main point was about the Father and the Son, and reconciling Jesus saying "I and the father are one," and all those scriptures of them being separate beings.

Comment: Yes, again, agreed with the obvious separate entity theme here. But you have constructed a Godhead around the three, necessitating a HS entity to make the 3. As the HS is not (according to scripture, not tradition), then Jesus doesn't have to be either. He is a man, made like us, Heb 2:17. Either he is, or he isn't, we can't have it both ways. You can click my name to search for HS posts.

Comment: You have 134 posts, I would really appreciate it if you know the title of one of such a nature.

Comment: try this one https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/83245/if-you-do-not-believe-the-holy-spirit-is-a-person-then-what-is-it-what-do-bibl/83249?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C43.2577#83249

Comment: @steveowen And to clarify, the point of what I said does not require the HS to be involved anyway, so just ignore that part and try to understand what I'm saying; ***I*** have not constructed a Godhead, you said that I said The Father and the Son are "one God", which, ***I*** didn't, the scriptures recorded when Jesus said, "I and the Father are one", I was clearing that up because you were confused by it because they are separate beings, and so I tried to clarify in what way Jesus meant that they were "one".

Comment: @steveowen I have read your post, and personally, I can't believe you didn't catch how it indicated the Spirit as a separate entity, but I do think the most important part was where you said, "there is no need to see the Holy Spirit as distinct from the Father or God" and cited 1 Cor 8:6 "for us there is but one God, the Father, from whom all things came and for whom we live; and there is but one Lord, Jesus Christ, through whom all things came and through whom we live", but, if you say you'll read it, I can write what will probably be a little long, showing the clear separate being.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140971/discussion-between-robert-bradley-and-steveowen).

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks: "How do non-trinitarians resolve the clear indications that both the Father and Jesus are God?" Other answers so far have focused on refuting the claim that there are actually "clear indications" that the Father and Jesus are God. Another non-trinitarian approach would be to admit that certain biblical passages do indeed give such indications, but other verses provide evidence to the contrary. In other words, a non-trinitarian approach is not necessarily an approach that accepts biblical inerrancy in its entirety. Once the Bible is accepted as containing doctrines which originate from human beings as well as from God, the issue may be resolved by rejecting certain passages as untrue.

All of the proof-texts offered by the OP are from the Gospel of John. So to resolve the problem, a non-trinitarian need only point out that John's Christology is atypical and need not be considered the final word on the subject. John clearly did believe that "the Word was God" and that the Word became flesh in the person of Jesus Christ. John also depicts Jesus as saying "Before Abraham was I am."  So, rather than arguing that John really meant something other than what is suggested by these verses, a non-trinitarian may simply dismiss these verses because John's Gospel is ahistorical and teaches a [high Christology](https://artiosmagazine.org/god-thoughts/christology-john/) which other apostles and Jesus himself did not truly teach.

An example of this kind of approach is found among the scholars of the Jesus Seminar, who found only one saying in the Gospel of John that was likely to be something that Jesus said.

> “Most scholars, if they had worked through the sayings as we had,
> would tend to agree there is virtually nothing in the fourth Gospel
> that goes back to Jesus,” said Robert Fortna of Vassar College. Jesus
> says in John “I am the good shepherd . . . I am the light of the world
> . . . I am the bread of life,” but that “is mostly the work of the
> author,” Fortna said. Jesus rarely refers to himself in the other
> Gospels. [source](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1991-03-04-mn-77-story.html)

**Conclusion: while non-trinitarians often defend their views by interpreting biblical verses differently from traditional Christians, they also sometimes simply reject the authority of the sources in question, including the proof texts mentioned in the OP.**

---

*Note: The example from the Jesus Seminar above should not be understood to imply that the Seminar consists only of non-trinitarians but as an example of an attitude which certain non-trinitarians might hold.*